# Pano ID Not pulling Up correct user contributed pano

Tags: google-maps

I have a pano that I created and submitted a while ago.
https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/107171937649357455960/photos/@30.2665291,-81.389295,3a,90y,10.99h,89.33t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1s-8L-XDwFrK_0%2FVXdQjZSGbSI%2FAAAAAAAABbM%2F9542s2jtYjY!2e4!3e11!6s%2F%2Flh4.googleusercontent.com%2F-8L-XDwFrK_0%2FVXdQjZSGbSI%2FAAAAAAAABbM%2F9542s2jtYjY%2Fw203-h100-k-no%2F!7i2508!8i1254

I had it embedded in a simple html file.  But it stopped working when google switched things around.  I've since gotten an API key, tried to plug it in but I getting "The Google Maps API server rejected your request. Invalid request. Unexpected parameter 'panoid'."

I'm trying to find my panoID and I cannot.  I tried using this site:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start
to help me generate the code with the PanoID that I had before but it pulls up an adjacent location but not my actual Pano I created.

```
<iframe width="853" height="480" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/streetview?key=my_key_goes_here&panoid=uxuPpX3AX8sAAAQYJKfvaw"></iframe><div><small><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/views/view/107171937649357455960/gphoto/6058198667222033330" style="color:#0000FF; text-align:left">Mobile Photo Lab</a> by Glossy Finish</small></div>
```

So how do I reference my pano or find my correct PanoID?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsfiddle showing your panorama with the Google Maps Javascript API v3](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/dLu0yteq/3/).

That gives me the panoid (y4y-RLqAzd4AAAQqZO87tA).  Entering that in the [embedded map "wizard"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start) gives me this:

```
 <iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/streetview?pano=y4y-RLqAzd4AAAQqZO87tA&key=..." allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

That gives me [your custom pano](http://www.geocodezip.com/example_embedded_map_streetview.html)

Comment: perfect, thanks! Now i just need to figure out how to get the API to allow my site to load.  But almost there.